# bash changes its behavior depending on the value of the "IFS" variable

Tags: bash, shell

When I set the `IFS` variable to a space, `bash` treats multiple spaces as one space (`myprogram` is a program that prints the command line arguments it receives):

```
IFS=" "
x="hello   hi   world"
./myprogram $x
argv[1] = hello
argv[2] = hi
argv[3] = world
```

But when I set the `IFS` variable to a comma, `bash` does not treat multiple commas as one comma:

```
IFS=","
x="hello,,,hi,,,world"
./myprogram $x
argv[1] = hello
argv[2] = 
argv[3] = 
argv[4] = hi
argv[5] = 
argv[6] = 
argv[7] = world
```

Why is that?

Comment: Just for reference, "IFS" means **Internal Field Separator**.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is documented in `man bash`.  A single occurrence of any character in IFS that is not whitespace delimits a field.

From `man bash`:

> The  shell  treats  each  character of IFS as a delimiter, and
>   splits the results of the other expansions into words using these
>   characters as field terminators.  If IFS is    unset, or its value is
>   exactly `<space><tab><newline>`, the default, then sequences of `<space>`,
>   `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and end of the results of  the 
>   previous    expansions  are  ignored, and any sequence of IFS
>   characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words.  If
>   IFS has a value other than the default, then sequences    of the
>   whitespace characters space, tab, and newline are ignored at the
>   beginning and end of the word, as long as the whitespace character is
>   in the value of  IFS  (an  IFS    whitespace  character).  **Any
>   character in IFS that is not IFS whitespace, along with any adjacent
>   IFS whitespace characters, delimits a field.  A sequence of IFS
>   whitespace    characters is also treated as a delimiter.**  If the value
>   of IFS is null, no word splitting occurs.  [Emphasis added.]

#### Examples: field splitting

If IFS has no whitespace characters, then whitespace is included in the fields:

```
$ ( IFS=',' x='one , two,three'; printf "<%s>\n" $x )
<one >
< two>
<three>
```

If IFS has both blanks and a comma, then sequences of blanks, followed by a comma, followed by sequences of blanks are treated as a single delimiter:

```
$ ( IFS=' ,' x='one , two,three'; printf "<%s>\n" $x )
<one>
<two>
<three>
```

Sequences of commas are interpreted as sequences of empty fields:

```
$ ( IFS=' ,' x='one,,,two,three'; printf "<%s>\n" $x )
<one>
<>
<>
<two>
<three>
```

#### Examples: leading and trailing whitespace

If IFS contains no whitespace, then any leading and trailing whitespace is kept in the fields:

```
$ ( IFS=',' x='  one , two,three  ,'; printf "<%s>\n" $x )
<  one >
< two>
<three  >
```

If IFS does contain blanks, then any leading or trailing sequences of blanks are removed:

```
$ ( IFS=' ,' x='  one , two,three  ,'; printf "<%s>\n" $x )
<one>
<two>
<three>
```

Comment: maybe also worth emphasizing "then sequences of the whitespace characters space, tab, and newline are ignored at the beginning and end of the word, as long as the whitespace character is in the value of IFS"

Comment: @JeffSchaller Excellent idea:  I just added a section on that.

Comment: Also: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05

Comment: what if you have a tab-separated file with some missing values? i.e. you don't want sequences of tabs to be treated as a single tab. Also, the fields contain commas so can't use that as a delimiter. Is the only solution to use some other delimiter (not tabs)?

Comment: @Davos For data with each field delimited by a single tab, it may be more natural to use other tools that handle this easily such as `awk` with the `-F'\t'` option or `cut`.  Alternatively, if you have a recent version of `bash`, you may be able to parse the fields using `readarray` with the `-d$'\t'` option.